# UITableView is not reloading

Tags: refresh, uitableview, reload, restkit

here is the situation:

I have a "UITableViewController" which loads objects with RestKits "RKFetchedResultsTableController". After clicking on a cell I switch to a detail UITableViewController also driven by a "RKFetchedResultsTableController" which gives me a corresponding answer text for the selected object.

The problem is now, if I go back to the first "UITableViewController" and select another object in the table the old answer text from the previous selected object is in the detail table. If I use the "pullToRefresh" function the table gets refreshed and the correct answer is loading.

Why is the old answer from the previous object still in the tableView and not the correct answer for the new selected Object even if I tell [tableController loadTable] in the viewWillAppear method.

Answer (score 0):

AppDelegate:

@

```
interface AppDelegate ()
@property (nonatomic, strong, readwrite) RKObjectManager *objectManager;
@property (nonatomic, strong, readwrite) RKManagedObjectStore *objectStore;
@end;

@implementation AppDelegate

@synthesize window = _window, isAuthenticated;
@synthesize objectManager;
@synthesize objectStore;

- (void)initializeRestKit
{
    //self.objectManager = [RKObjectManager managerWithBaseURLString:@"http://falling-ocean-1302.herokuapp.com"];
    self.objectManager = [RKObjectManager managerWithBaseURLString:@"http://falling-ocean-1302.herokuapp.com"];
    self.objectManager.serializationMIMEType = RKMIMETypeJSON;
    self.objectManager.acceptMIMEType = RKMIMETypeJSON; 
    self.objectStore = [RKManagedObjectStore objectStoreWithStoreFilename:@"MMmtvzme.sqlite"];
    self.objectManager.objectStore = self.objectStore;
    self.objectManager.mappingProvider = [MMMappingProvider mappingProviderWithObjectStore:self.objectStore];
    self.objectManager.client.cachePolicy = RKRequestCachePolicyNone;

    RKLogConfigureByName("RestKit", RKLogLevelTrace); 
    RKLogConfigureByName("RestKit/Network", RKLogLevelTrace); 
    RKLogConfigureByName("RestKit/ObjectMapping", RKLogLevelTrace); 
    RKLogConfigureByName("RestKit/Network/Queue", RKLogLevelTrace);


    // Enable automatic network activity indicator management
    objectManager.client.requestQueue.showsNetworkActivityIndicatorWhenBusy = YES;

    [objectManager.router routeClass:[MMRequest class] toResourcePath:@"/requests" forMethod:RKRequestMethodPOST];
    [objectManager.router routeClass:[MMRequest class] toResourcePath:@"/requests" forMethod:RKRequestMethodDELETE];

    [objectManager.router routeClass:[MMAnswer class] toResourcePath:@"/requests/:request_id/answers" forMethod:RKRequestMethodPOST];
}
```

Ok this is the code from the first UITableViewController

```
    @interface MMMyRequestList ()
    @property (nonatomic, strong) RKFetchedResultsTableController *tableController;
    @end

    @implementation MMMyRequestList

    @synthesize tableController;




- (void)viewDidLoad
    {
        [super viewDidLoad];

        [self configureRKTableController];
        [self configureCellMapping];
        [self useCustomNib];

    }

    - (void)configureRKTableController{
        self.tableController = [[RKObjectManager sharedManager] fetchedResultsTableControllerForTableViewController:self];
        self.tableController.autoRefreshFromNetwork = YES;
        self.tableController.pullToRefreshEnabled = YES;
        self.tableController.resourcePath = @"/requests";
        self.tableController.variableHeightRows = YES;
        NSSortDescriptor *descriptor = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"request_id" ascending:NO];
        self.tableController.sortDescriptors = [NSArray arrayWithObject:descriptor];
        tableController.canEditRows = YES;      
    }


    - (void)configureCellMapping{
        RKTableViewCellMapping *cellMapping = [RKTableViewCellMapping cellMapping];
        cellMapping.cellClassName = @"MMRequestCell";
        cellMapping.reuseIdentifier = @"MMRequest";
        cellMapping.rowHeight = 100.0;
        [cellMapping mapKeyPath:@"title" toAttribute:@"requestLabel.text"];
        [cellMapping mapKeyPath:@"user.first_name" toAttribute:@"userLabel.text"];

        cellMapping.onSelectCellForObjectAtIndexPath = ^(UITableViewCell *cell, id object, NSIndexPath* indexPath) 
        {
            MMMyRequestListAnswer * uic = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"MMMyRequestListAnswer"];
            MMRequest *request = [self.tableController objectForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
            if ([uic respondsToSelector:@selector(setRequest:)]) {
                [uic setRequest:request];
            }
            [self.navigationController pushViewController:uic animated:YES];
        };


        [tableController mapObjectsWithClass:[MMRequest class] toTableCellsWithMapping:cellMapping];
    }

    - (void)useCustomNib{
        [self.tableView registerNib:[UINib nibWithNibName:@"MMRequestCell" bundle:nil] forCellReuseIdentifier:@"MMRequest"];
    }

    - (void)objectLoader:(RKObjectLoader*)objectLoader didFailWithError:(NSError*)error {
        UIAlertView* alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error" 
                                                        message:[error localizedDescription] 
                                                       delegate:nil 
                                              cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];

        [alert show];
        NSLog(@"Hit error: %@", error);
    }

    - (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
        [super viewWillAppear:animated];

        /**
         Load the table view!
         */
        [tableController loadTable];

    }
```

After clicking on a cell the Detail UIViewController come into action

```
    interface MMMyRequestListAnswer ()
    @property (nonatomic, strong) RKFetchedResultsTableController *tableController;

    @end

    @implementation MMMyRequestListAnswer
    @synthesize tableHeaderView, requestTextLabel;
    @synthesize request;
    @synthesize tableController;



 - (void)viewDidLoad
    {
        [super viewDidLoad];

        [self configureRKTableController];
        [self configureCellMapping];
        [self useCustomNib];
    }


    - (void)configureRKTableController{
        self.tableController = [[RKObjectManager sharedManager] fetchedResultsTableControllerForTableViewController:self];
        self.tableController.autoRefreshFromNetwork = YES;
        self.tableController.pullToRefreshEnabled = YES;
        self.tableController.resourcePath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"/requests/%i/answers", [self.request.request_id intValue]];
        self.tableController.variableHeightRows = YES;
        NSSortDescriptor *descriptor = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"answer_id" ascending:NO];
        self.tableController.sortDescriptors = [NSArray arrayWithObject:descriptor];
    }


    - (void)configureCellMapping{
        RKTableViewCellMapping *cellMapping = [RKTableViewCellMapping cellMapping];
        cellMapping.cellClassName = @"MMRequestAnswerCell";
        cellMapping.reuseIdentifier = @"MMAnswer";
        cellMapping.rowHeight = 80.0;
        [cellMapping mapKeyPath:@"text" toAttribute:@"answerLabel.text"];
        [cellMapping mapKeyPath:@"user.first_name" toAttribute:@"userLabel.text"];
        [tableController mapObjectsWithClass:[MMAnswer class] toTableCellsWithMapping:cellMapping];
    }

    - (void)useCustomNib{
        [self.tableView registerNib:[UINib nibWithNibName:@"MMRequestAnswerCell" bundle:nil] forCellReuseIdentifier:@"MMAnswer"];
    }

    - (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
        [super viewWillAppear:animated];

        /**
         Load the table view!
         */
        [tableController loadTable];  

    }
```

The Object Mapping is handled in this Class:

```
@implementation MMMappingProvider

@synthesize objectStore;

+ (id)mappingProviderWithObjectStore:(RKManagedObjectStore *)objectStore {
    return [[self alloc] initWithObjectStore:objectStore];    
}

- (id)initWithObjectStore:(RKManagedObjectStore *)theObjectStore {
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        self.objectStore = theObjectStore;

        [self setObjectMapping:[self requestObjectMapping] forResourcePathPattern:@"/requests" withFetchRequestBlock:^NSFetchRequest *(NSString *resourcePath) {
            NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [MMRequest fetchRequest];
            return fetchRequest;
        }];

        [self setObjectMapping:[self answerObjectMapping] forResourcePathPattern:@"/requests/:request_id/answers" withFetchRequestBlock:^NSFetchRequest *(NSString *resourcePath) {
            NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [MMAnswer fetchRequest];
            fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = [NSArray arrayWithObject:[NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"answer_id" ascending:YES]];
            return fetchRequest;
        }];

        [self setSerializationMapping:[self.requestObjectMapping inverseMapping] forClass:[MMRequest class]];
        [self setSerializationMapping:[self.answerObjectMapping inverseMapping] forClass:[MMAnswer class]];
        [self setSerializationMapping:[self.userObjectMapping inverseMapping] forClass:[MMUser class]];

}

    return self;
}


- (RKManagedObjectMapping *)userObjectMapping {
    RKManagedObjectMapping *mapping =  [RKManagedObjectMapping mappingForEntityWithName:@"MMUser" inManagedObjectStore:self.objectStore];
    mapping.primaryKeyAttribute = @"user_id";

    [mapping mapAttributes:@"first_name", nil];
    [mapping mapKeyPathsToAttributes:
     @"id", @"user_id",
     nil];

    return mapping;
}

- (RKManagedObjectMapping *)answerObjectMapping {
    RKManagedObjectMapping *mapping = [RKManagedObjectMapping mappingForEntityWithName:@"MMAnswer" inManagedObjectStore:self.objectStore];
    mapping.primaryKeyAttribute = @"answer_id";

    [mapping mapAttributes:@"text",@"request_id",@"user_id", nil];
    [mapping mapKeyPathsToAttributes:
     @"id", @"answer_id",
     nil];

    [mapping mapKeyPath:@"user" toRelationship:@"user" withMapping:[self userObjectMapping]];
    [mapping mapKeyPath:@"request" toRelationship:@"request" withMapping:[self requestObjectMapping]];

    return mapping;
}

- (RKManagedObjectMapping *)requestObjectMapping {
    RKManagedObjectMapping *mapping = [RKManagedObjectMapping mappingForEntityWithName:@"MMRequest" inManagedObjectStore:self.objectStore];

    mapping.primaryKeyAttribute = @"request_id";

    [mapping mapAttributes:@"title",@"user_id", nil];
    [mapping mapKeyPathsToAttributes:
     @"id", @"request_id",
     nil];

    [mapping mapKeyPath:@"user" toRelationship:@"user" withMapping:[self userObjectMapping]];

    return mapping;    
}
```

Comment: One thing I have noticed is, that when the core data consists no data. The reloading is working fine. But as soon as the object is stored in core data if have the problem mentioned in in the first post.

Answer (score 0):

OK Figured it out!!! Some digging revealed that I was loading my UITableviewcontroller BEFORE the mapping provider.

The fix was, to take [self initialiserestkit] method in - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions

and put it before any of the code in this method (i.e. make [self initialiserestkit] the first line of the didfinishlaunchingwithoptions method.

Issue solved. Now the tableview is loaded AFTER the mappings so everything works as it should.

Comment: Just realised this answer may not be applicable to you :(.